# Swift: getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when trying to get NSDate future date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I wrote a function to get next Monday's `NSDate` based on today's date, but I am getting a `runtime error` when I try to call this function.

I am receiving an error that says:

**Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)**

on this line:

```
calendar?.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
```

Why is this happening?? And what steps do I need to do to fix this?

```
func getNextMonday() -> NSDate {
    let today = NSDate()
    var calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
    calendar!.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

    let components = calendar!.components(.YearCalendarUnit | .WeekOfYearCalendarUnit | .HourCalendarUnit | .MinuteCalendarUnit | .SecondCalendarUnit, fromDate: today)
    components.weekday = 2
    components.weekOfYear = components.weekOfYear + 1
    components.hour = 8
    components.minute = 0
    components.second = 0

    if let nextMonday = calendar?.dateFromComponents(components) {
        return nextMonday
    }
    else {
        return today
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried unwrapping the optional calendar `calendar!.locale = ...`?

Comment: @Eimantas /foreheadslap That was it! Make it an answer so I can accept! Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that this fixes the problem? (I do not see how this makes a difference.) It seems to me that the real error is that you should use .WeekOfYearCalendarUnit instead of .WeekCalendarUnit.

Comment: @MartinR Already fixed that issue. I have updated the code to reflect the update.

Comment: Do not change the code in the question to show the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unwrapping the optional `calendar`:

```
calendar!.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
```